# Cipher Crypto Encryption incorrect key generation in Linux but working fine on Windows Machine

Tags: java, linux, encryption, base64, encryption-asymmetric

Following are the details of the issue along with Code Snippets-

**Overview** - The purpose of the program is to upload Invoice data to Portal and Receive back the acknowledgement.

**Issue**   - When we run the program and hit API from Windows machines, it is working fine and getting the response code 200 OK.
But when the same is executed from Linux machines, Response code 500 is received , response message - "Internal Sever Error."

**Java Version** - openjdk version "1.8.0_222"

**One Jar Dependency** - org.json.jar

**Same program is running flawlessly on Windows.**
If I generate the AppkKey and Password from windows and use it on linux. It worked.

**Methods used for AppKey and Password Generation.**

```
String appkeye = encryptAsymmetricKey(publicKey, new String(appKey));
String password = encryptAsymmetricKey(publicKey, "UserId");

public static String encryptAsymmetricKey(String pubkey, String password) throws Exception {
    PublicKey publicKeys = convertPubStringToKey(pubkey);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeys);
    byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
    String encryptedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText);
    return encryptedPassword;
}

public static String encryptAsymmetricKey(String pubkey, byte[] appKey) throws Exception {
    PublicKey publicKeys = convertPubStringToKey(pubkey);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeys);
    byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(appKey);
    return null;
}

private static PublicKey convertPubStringToKey(String publikkey) {
    PublicKey pubKey = null;
    byte[] publicBytes=Base64.getDecoder().decode(publikkey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory;
    try {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pubKey;
}

public static byte[] createAESKey() {
    byte[] appKey = null;
    try {
        KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        gen.init(256);
        SecretKey secret = gen.generateKey();
        appKey = secret.getEncoded();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

    }
    return appKey;
}
```

Please suggest

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Windows uses SHA1PRNG to generate keys while linux uses NativePRNG which comes from /dev/random or /dev/urandom. Make sure Linux is also using SHA1PRNG. I ran into this problem before. Maybe the following will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107982/rhe-7-not-respecting-java-secure-random-seed

Comment: `new String(appKey)` is two bugs; failure to specify the charset and attempting to create a string from an arbitrary binary array. `password.getBytes()` is a bug failure to specify charset. `encryptAsymmetricKey(String pubkey, byte[] appKey)` is a bug; it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - Thanks for suggestion. The above code block missed the declaration

new String(appKey) declaration is as under-
`byte[] appKey = createAESKey();`

Comment: I ran your program (after correcting the errors mentioned by @ President James K. Polk) successfully on my Windows 10 desktop (OpenJava 11.0.8) and under Linus (Java 1.8.0.66) in an online environment, so it should have nothing to do with the OP-system is running on.