# how to make SecureRandom to be constant using seedBytes in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a kotlin android application and I need to use seed bytes to generate a secure random. how can I make the secure random to give the same number for the same seed bytes?
this is my code:

```
val seedBytes = byteArrayOf(116,-64,24,11,126,59,70,-12,68,-39,-33,65,-38,-88,-75,87,97,-112,-22,-64,12,44,-2,-41,-28,-52,82,107,-109,-66,47,41,-59,-44,-114,-95,80,-83,37,107,27,-93,-38,-116,37,-60,-97,98,-102,-61,-50,-83,69,27,11,-12,116,26,59,21,116,69,-90,-19);
val RANDOM = SecureRandom(seedBytes);
println(RANDOM) // => I want this print to always be the same
```

but right now for example one time I get

```
java.security.SecureRandom@c708450
```

and the other time I get

```
java.security.SecureRandom@de2e6b1
```

Comment: It's been a while but I thought the whole point of SecureRandom was to generate different sequences *even with* the same seed. From the JavaDoc "SecureRandom must produce non-deterministic output."

Comment: @Michael I need it to be the same for the user to be able to recover his private key

Comment: Seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107982/rhe-7-not-respecting-java-secure-random-seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was to extend the android's SecureRandom and then re implement it with the java original code that permits generating same secure random with the same seed. it is not possible to do it with Android's built in Secure random because the possibility to create the same random with the same seed has been deprecated in Android N and was removed in Android P

Answer (score 1):

Your not getting a value from the random, but printing the instance of the random you have created. You cannot make this the same each time however if you call `nextInt()` for example it will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You've done it. You're a bit confused about that output.

> `System.out.println(someObj)`

This is just syntax sugar for `System.out.println(someObj.toString());`.

The default `toString()` implementation, as found in `java.lang.Object`, is this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + printAsHex(System.identityHashCode(this));
}
```

In other words, that `@c708450` stuff is the system's identity hash code for your SecureRandom instance. This is, vastly oversimplifying, it's memory address. The point is: If you have 2 identical references, the number is the same. That's all it does, it is otherwise meaningless, **and every object in the system has this**, it has nothing whatsoever to do with Random / SecureRandom, and the location in heap memory where the SecureRandom instance is at, has zero effect on the random numbers it spits out. In other words, that `@foo` thing is **not** the seed value. It is a number that has no meaning at all, other than when it is the same as another identity hash code.

The API of Random **does not offer** a way to get the seed value, nor to get the 'distance' from it. Therefore, it is not immediately obvious how one would ascertain that two separate instances of SecureRandom are going to produce the same sequence forever.

However, in practice, just invoke `.nextInt()` 100 times on both and if the same 100 numbers fall out? Rest assured.

Thus, if you want to print a 'footprint' of where your secure random is it, print a few invokes of `.nextInt()` or `.nextByte()`. This is more involved than just `System.out.println(theSecureRandomInstance)` - there is no easy way out; you'll have to write a method that does this (and be aware that this will advance the sequence, of course. You also can't shove em back in, either).

Comment: Actually the problem is that even with the same seed, every time I get a different result for the nextInt() method, I read that the possibility to create the same random with the same seed has been deprecated in Android N and was removed in Android P